# How to pass a special value for the first item in laravel foreach loop in CONTROLLER

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I'am just trying to pass a special value for my array in CONTROLLER where this value will be effect only for the first item in the `foreach` loop. I know how to implement this in view (`$loop ->first`) . But this can't be used inside a controller.

I have a table with prices where this table contain both $ and £. So what I'm doing is all the values in the table will be loop through the `foreach` loop and I'm currently adding few more items in to array with some if conditions. Please refer below code.

```
$sortAccordingToPrice =  [];
foreach($listings as $dbValues){

    if(($dbValues['ref'] == ConstatntE::E['id'] )  ) {

        $newPrice = array(

            'converted_price' => $dbValues["price"] * Session::get('LRK') , 
            'id' => $dbValues["id"],
            'seller_logo' => $dbValues['APT']["RFL"],
            'ref' => $dbValues['ref'],

        );

        array_push($sortAccordingToPrice , $newPrice);

    }else{

        $newPrice = array(

            'converted_price' => $dbValues['APT']["price"],
            'id' => $dbValues["id"] ,
            'seller_logo' => $dbValues['APT']["RFL"],
            'ref' => $dbValues['ref']
          );
        array_push($sortAccordingToPrice , $newPrice);
    }
}
```

So what I wants to do is to add `'isLowest' => TRUE` only for the first element of the both if conditions. Means if first if statement true then `'isLowest' => TRUE` will be added to the array for the first time and when the second if condition gets true `'isLowest' => TRUE` also will be included into the array.

**Please note I'm not asking in the `.blade.php`** I wants to do this in the **Controller**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Type:1** you may use `array_key_first`

```
foreach($listings as $key => $dbValues){
    if ($key === array_key_first($listings)){
    echo 'FIRST ELEMENT!';
    }  
}
```

**Type:2** you may use the key as well.

```
foreach($listings as $key => $dbValues){
    if ($key === 0){
    echo 'FIRST ELEMENT!';
    }  
}
```

**Type: 3** The first time you'll get true then it'll be false.

```
$first = true; 
foreach ($listings as $key => $value)
{
  if ( $first )
  {
    // do something
    $first = false; //in order not to get into the if statement for the next loops
  }
  else
  {
    // do something else for all loops except the first
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the other syntax for a foreach loop

```
foreach($listings as $idx => $dbValues){
```

then inside the loop you can code

```
    if( $idx == 0 ) {
        // the first time round the foreach loop
        // do whatever is required only on the frst time round the loop
```